# Unable to calculate the ratio of two metrics in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, metrics, promql

I am collecting ZFS metrics in Prometheus v.2.19 from Linux servers using [ZFS Exporter](https://github.com/mac133k/zfs_exporter). The data is being collected from all targets and the values are correct, however there is this strange issue: I want to calculate the percentage of the ratio of ARC misses vs. ARC hits, so I use the following formula:

```
100 * rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='misses'}[5m]) / rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='hits'}[5m])
```

but it produces no data. I can get the values from each of the rate expressions individually, but not from the above formula. If I use the formula with the same labels, ie.:

```
100 * rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='hits'}[5m]) / rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='hits'}[5m])
```

it gives the correct results of 100, because the ratio of misses to misses or hits to hits is always 1:1. I tried similar formulas with metrics from other sources (ie. PCP, Collectd) and those work fine, ie. I could calculate ratios of same metrics with different labels, so it seems like the problem could be specific to the metrics from ZFS Exporter. This exporter has a very few metrics, but each metric has many different stats identified by the value of the 'stat' label. All the metrics are of gauge type, but I do not think it really matters for the `rate` function in PromQL. Anyway like I mentioned before the rates can be computed separately, only the ratio fails. Somebody please suggest how to tackle this issue.

Comment: I was actually after the hit percentage where the formula is: `100 * rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='hits'}[5m]) / ignoring(stat) (rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='hits'}[5m]) + ignoring(stat) rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='misses'}[5m]))`

Comment: A commit was made in https://github.com/mac133k/zfs_exporter to address this issue, so now the code in the master branch contains a new metric namespace without excessive labeling. The old metric naming is still available in the `labelhell` branch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prometheus divides one metric by another only if all the labels with their values for both metrics are identical. In this case metrics on the left side of `/` have label `{stat='misses'}`, while metrics on the right side have different value for `stat` label: `{stat='hits'}`. Prometheus provides `ignoring` and `on` operations, which may be applied to any binary operator (i.e. `/`, `+`, `-`, etc.). See [the corresponding docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) for details.

So in you case you must tell Prometheus to ignore `stat` label when performing calculations:

```
100 * rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='misses'}[5m]) / ignoring(stat) rate(zfs_arc_stats{stat='hits'}[5m])
```